# ListView returning the wrong list and position

Tags: java, android, xml, listview, android-adapter

basically I have 2 ListViews; Arrivals/Departures and when you click on the item in either list it would return the title however when I click anything in my "Departure" list it returns elements from my Arrivals list, here are my listeners! Any help would be appreciated

here is where I set the each list

```
    ListView DeparturesListView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.Departures);
    ThreeHorizontalTextViewsAdapter threeHorizontalTextViewsAdapter1 = new ThreeHorizontalTextViewsAdapter(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.three_horizontal_textviews_layout, DeparturesList);
    DeparturesListView.setAdapter(threeHorizontalTextViewsAdapter1);
    ListView ArrivalsListView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.Arrivals);
    ThreeHorizontalTextViewsAdapter threeHorizontalTextViewsAdapter2 = new ThreeHorizontalTextViewsAdapter(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.three_horizontal_textviews_layout, ArrivalsList);
    ArrivalsListView.setAdapter(threeHorizontalTextViewsAdapter2);
```

These are my listeners

```
    ArrivalsListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener()
    {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position, long arg3)
        {
            ThreeStrings temp2 = (ThreeStrings) ArrivalsListView.getAdapter().getItem(position);
            TrainService ArrivalTrain = temp2.getTrain();
            Log.d("templor", "ARRIVAL: "+ArrivalTrain.getOrigin().getLocationName().toString());
        }
    });
    DeparturesListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener()
    {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position, long arg3)
        {

            ThreeStrings temp = (ThreeStrings) DeparturesListView.getAdapter().getItem(position);
            TrainService service = temp.getTrain();
            Log.d("templor", "DEPARTURE"+service.getOrigin().getLocationName().toString());
        }
    });
```

Comment: Could be a chance that you have passed departures collection to arrival listview and arrival to departures. Just a guess.

Comment: What is the "service" variable pointing to?

Comment: Hi, the 'service' Variable is the same as the above ArrivalTrain variable, I just forgot to rename it to "Departure" @SripadRaj, I added the only other reference to either listView! Thanks a lot :)

Comment: So that solves the problem then. :)

Comment: No no, the variable name is irellevent, it gets the object from temp.getTrain() which in turn gets it from the Departure listView. It is still not functioning correctly :P